# jQuery event delegation and attachment issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a set of three elements. And there are many coming elements after the page load by ajax when the user clicks on a certain element. I iterate over initial elements with each and attach an event to them like this:

```
tagSet.each(function(index, element){

   tagSet.eq(index).on("click",function(){alert("Alerted! Clicked")});
}
```

But with this approach those ajax-created elements would not be attached with an event. Thus I have to make a little bit of change to on() for it accommodate the ajax-created elements:

```
tagSet.each(function(index, element){

   $(document).on("click",tagSet.eq(index),function(){alert("Alerted! Clicked")});
}
```

It solve the problem of event attachment to those ajax-created elements but raises another issue. It attaches the event in a way that all of the elements of the page gets trigged with that specific event at once. I mean, since I have three elements, a click on one of them cause all three `alert("Alerted!Clicke!)` to trigger. What is the issue and the solution?

Comment: You need to pass a selector as the 2nd param to `.on`.

Comment: Show us what tagSet is, and we'll show you how to avoid that silly loop

Comment: tagSet is a match set of three `<span>` tag

Comment: That doesn't really help much, it's like saying I have a bucket of something that is stuck, can you get it out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation to bind to all current and future items that match a query:

```
$(document).on("click", ".some-class-here", function(){
    alert("Alerted! Clicked")
});
```

Replace `.some-class-here` with a selector that matches your `tagSet` elements. Then remove your call to `$.each`.

Comment: would you explain more about `$.each`

Comment: Using `each` binds an event handler to the `document` element once for each item in `tagSet`. This defeats one of the purposes of using event delegation (fewer event handlers for a single event.)